# Anything wrong with running PHP and Ruby on the same Apache server?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, hosting

We are trying to figure out the best way to distribute our applications among our available servers, which are few in number.

Assuming adequate RAM and CPU power, is there any reason we shouldn't run `mod_php` and `mod_rails` (Passenger) within the same Apache server? Would they clash or conflict somehow?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is little risk with running mod_php and mod_rails on the same Apache server.

In fact, Passenger won't affect Apache if it goes down so it is actually a good choice to use with Apache and mod_php. From the [Passenger Architectural Overview](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Design%20and%20Architecture.html#_overview):

> It should be noted that the Ruby on
>   Rails application does not run in the
>   same address space as Apache. This
>   differentiates Passenger from other
>   application-server-inside-web-server
>   software such as mod_php, mod_perl and
>   mod_ruby. If the Rails application
>   crashes or leak memory, it will have
>   no effect on Apache. In fact,
>   stability is one of our highest goals.
>   Passenger is carefully designed and
>   implemented so that Apache shouldn't
>   crash because of Passenger.

Comment: I cannat understand, what is the risk then?

Comment: @pahnin I think he meant `almost no risk` by `a little risk`.